# Entity is not validating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

My Designer.cs is as follows,

```
namespace CeremonyApp
{
    . . .

   [EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="CeremonyDBModel", Name="GuestParty")]
    [Serializable()]
    [DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]    
    public partial class GuestParty : EntityObject
    {
          . . .
    }

   . . .
}
```

I am validating entity `(GuestParty)` in Model `(Validation.cs)` having the following code,

```
namespace CeremonyApp.Models
{    
    public class Validation
    {        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Testing")]        
        public String TableNo { get; set; }
    }

    [MetadataType(typeof(Validation))]
    public partial class GuestParty
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is, if i put the `[MetadataType(typeof(Validation))]` in `Designer.cs` at `GuestParty class`, it works but it does not if i put it here in `Validation.cs` as in the above code. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespaces are different.  Move your partial class and metadata back to namespace CeremonyApp.